# How can you find the name/identifier of a released object that's getting messages sent to it?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, instruments

I did the thing in Instruments that shows info about the object that was sent a message, but memory addresses are less than useful compared the actual name of the variable.  Is there a way to find out what it's identifier was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding symbolic breakpoints such as:

```
[NSException raise]
objc_exception_throw
malloc_error_break
```

Also try enabling NSZombies and you should be able to see the line of code that calls the release on the deallocated instance.